# CucumberOptions setting tags from a config.properties file

Tags: junit, tags, cucumber, appium, test-runner

I have a config.properties file in which I would like to add a 'tags' key-value pairing.  e.g.: tags:@ReadyToRun

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    tags = { "@Now" },      
    features = { "src/test/java/uk/gov/tfl/Reporting/Features" },
    glue = { "com.Reporting.StepDefinitions" }
    )
public class RunnerTest {}
```

The way I have been accessing my config.properties is using a class I created like this:

```
ConfigReader configReader = new ConfigReader();
String tags = configReader.GetConfigValueForKey("tags");
```

Any ideas how I can combine the two of these so that I can set the tags in the config.properties file to then be picked up by the TestRunner?

Cheers, Charlie

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit doubtful if this option can be an considered as an alternate for your requirement. 
Just by-passing the config properties and set the tags from command line.

If you are using Maven, you can set the Cucumber Options inline. (by appending the command with -Dcucumber.options). Then it looks like :

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @ReadyToRun"
```

Hope this solves your requirement.

Comment: I can give a try to configure the config properties to figure out if it is possible (if you still insist in using the properties file )